# Philanthropic wifi but... 

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet

I have a fibre broadband and plenty of spare bandwidth (and cash) so I decided to do a favour for my community and purchase a wireless router and custom high powered antenna so that people can use my wifi for free for a good 300 metres away.

I called the network 'FreeNet4UbutNoPornPlz' and let it run for bout a month. At one point I had around 20 mac addresses connected to the network, but I found out that a lot of them are visiting adult websites and bad stuff like that (using wireshark) so what can I do?

Shut it down and give up or just block specific mac addys? Can't people read the damn name? It is supposed to be a clue.

Comment: Seriously though, *what did you expect*?

Comment: exactly.. thats what one would get

Comment: i expect people to appreciate the freebie and not abuse it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Who knew that adults would use the internet for porn :/

I would suggest you take a look at your router and see if it support address filtering/adult filter etc.

If you have so much spare money, you can always look at getting a big filtering device, but, imho, it is overkill.

If you don't have the ability to add a filter, I would recommend switching to OpenDNS, adding the adult filter and proxy filter, then block EVERYTHING other than the normal ports (80/443/25/110/465/993 etc.), and even DNS to any address other than OpenDNS.

There is ways around everything, but this is the best I can think of.

Alternatively - set up logging and then put up a poster saying these Mac Addresses have been visiting porn along with a guide to tell partners how to check their partners machines :/ (mind you, you never know, they may be viewing sites together!)

Comment: lol @ 'porn offenders of the day' poster...

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a m0n0wall firewall box and a Captive Portal which requires a login. It might be possible to set it up to use an e-mail address for the login, then you'll have a list of users e-mails. If you don't want to do that set it up so that it presents a page to them when they log in with the terms and conditions (i.e rule no.1: no porn. rule number 2: see rule no.1) and warn that Mac address will be blocked if evidence has been found.

Or just start blocking MAC or domain addresses.